# How to avoid screen flickering with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular. I used AngularJS to develop front end. But at initial level I face issue for flickering some content when page is load.

My question is that when I run my app within localhost, sometimes it shows data binding expression on screen or it shows something crazy output on browser. I used `ng-clock` (suggest by angularjs docs) although my problem is not solved.

My html file is too small and not doing many thing although its flicker. Please note my script tag is placed on bottom. Please give me some idea to prevent this king of thing in AngularJS.

### index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Sample App</title>
        <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/cover.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sidebar.css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
 <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
        </script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                  <div class="masthead clearfix">
                      <div class="inner">
                          <div ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner" ng-clock>
                        <div ng-if="hasSidebar" ng-include src="'views/sidebar.html'" id="sidebar" ng-cloak></div>
                        <div id="view" ng-view></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mastfoot">
                      <div class="inner">
                          <p>Cover template</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

### header.html

```
<h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
        <li class="active"><a ng-href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#/features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### sidebar.html

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

### dashboard.html

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how it behaved when you used `ng-cloak`. Was there no difference at all compared to without `ng-cloak`?

Comment: Did you add the ngCloak CSS? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Did you include Css for ng-cloak?

Comment: There is no difference with the used of ng-clock, screen is fstill lickering for some time @JimAho

Comment: No,i have't used any css for ng-clock @MatthewGreen

Comment: what kind of css i have to used ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be caused because you're loading the AngularJS script at the bottom of the page.

Note that it is Angular itself that is hiding the element when you specify the `ng-cloak` directive.

Since your lettingt the browser render the page and *then* loading Angular, the time difference there might be causing the "flickering". Try to put your script tags at the top of the page.

Taken from the [AngularJS docs about ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head
>   section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must
>   be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

Comment: So, you mean that here need to used ng-clock in html file ??                   only thing is move angularjs script tag from bottom to head sections????

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your first question, please clarify. To answer your second question yes, you will need to move your script tags to the top of your page for best performance cloak-wise. The browser parses your page from top to bottom, so for the same reason you normally put script tags on the bottom of the page to improve page loading performance, you will need to put the script tags on the top of the page to let angular hide the element faster.

Comment: Also note that if you want Angular to use your version of jQuery you *must* put that script tag before the angular script tag. So if you decide to move Angular to the top of the page, consider moving jQuery as well. (your own app code could still be included at the bottom if you want to).

Comment: My question is that can i used ng-clock into html element those are rendering before parsing html ? or is there any other solutions for this ??

Comment: Follow the link I posted and read on there. You will see that you can add some CSS to your page and use `class="ng-cloak"` instead of the directive.

Comment: Thank you @Jim Aho i just update my css file and in html file i move script tag to head section and i think its solved my problem. thanx a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103326/discussion-between-tushar-balar-and-jim-aho).